# Execute icon missing sql server 2017

Tags: sql

Execute icon missing sql server 2017

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Choose View -> Toolbars -> SQL Editor to show it

Comment: Nice thanks! was searching for this a long time. Only today this page showed up